# gnome-terminal not work with reboot

Tags: linux

i try to open a terminal using gnome-terminal after system reboot,so i used the gnome-terminal in crontab.In normal cron it works.
ex : */1 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && gnome-terminal
but used with reboot option,it doesn't work
@reboot export DISPLAY=:0 && gnome-terminal
Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04,there is no autostart  directory under .config.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this without using cron.

Just following these steps:

1. Type "Startup Applications" in the search bar.
2. Click on the Startup Applications option. Then click "Add".
3. In the "name" field, type `Terminal`.
4. In the "command" field, type `gnome-terminal`.
5. Click "Add".

You're done! The next time you login, the terminal will launched automatically.